# Laravel mysql concurrent data select and update

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I want to run a for-loop with reading user table data and updating the same data constantly.

Step 1: Read `age` field from table `user` where `userID =1`

Step 2: Update `age` field of table `user`  set `age= age + 1` where `userID=1`

Step 3: Go to step 1 for 100 times

As I am selecting the data row as soon as I request for the data row update, I am missing the last updated data. How I can keep selecting the data record locked  until the latest update happens in the record? Can someone please help me with solution in laravel 4 or raw mysql.

Comment: Do you want to get the age field 100 times for the same userID? i mean does userID changes like 1,2,3,4...... or it is always fixed that userID=1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
DB::table('Users')->where('id', 1)->increment('age', 100);
```

For detail information [update in increment](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#updates)